# XML Parsing using Python converted to an exe file

Tags: python, xml, parsing, exe

I'm somewhat new to Python, and am trying to build a standalone parser. The actual parser works when executed through python, but I get an error when I try to run it after it's been converted into an exe file. I need it to be able to run without any third-party software.

The error says that there is no module named xml.dom

Help!

Comment: Which tool are you using to make exe files? The major ones are pyinstaller, cx_freeze and py2exe.

Answer (score 0):

I can not post comments currently, but if you are using py2exe, make sure you are ONLY importing modules from your python path. If you are not, you might want to check if your module goes into the same path your program specifies. Py2exe (if assuming you have it) creates two directories when it compiles (by default) and moves the executable into a dist folder that has all the modules in a zib file (called a library). Py2exe **WILL NOT** search for custom import statements to modules outside of your python path. Thus you must manually place the folder or module where ever the program originally called for it (within a folder, or the same directory the compiled exe is in.) Sorry if this isn't helpful.